# Поиск и замена фрагмента текста,введенные через запятую, в файле

Tags: java

Начинаю изучать java и для начала хотел сделать простую задачку: хочу перезаписать файл с заменой допустим 2 и 4 слова. пример такой строки из файла. слово0,слово1,слово2,слово3. Я хочу заменить 2 и 4 слово на "абрикос", и строка преобразуется в слово0,абрикос,слово2,абрикос. Я знаю о существовании о replace, но замена присваивает полю значение и не записывается в файл.
Буду рад любому совету. Спасибо!
Пример того как я считываю слова.

```
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
        String[] logon = scan.nextLine().split(",");
            System.out.println(logon[0]);
            System.out.println(logon[1]);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде будем использовать классы, которые появились в `Java 7` (и выше).

Я бы для начала попробовал реализовать такой алгоритм:

1. Открыли файл
2. Считали из него информацию в строку
3. Заменили в строке слова.
4. Записали новую строку в файл, старую удалили
5. Закрыли файл.

Это достаточно просто реализовать с помощью [`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) и [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). [Одна из многих статей по работе с ними](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/filewriter-i-filereader/). Либо же можно использовать метод `write` класса [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), что и покажу в ответе. Также отмечу, что данное решение совсем не оптимально и читает весь файл в память, если файл большой — оно не подходит. Но зато сама процедура замены делается в одну строку.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class ReplaceInFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "file.txt";
        String search = "вишня";
        String replace = "абрикос";
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Files.write(path,
            new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)
                .getBytes(charset));
        search = "арбуз";
        Files.write(path,
            new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)
                .getBytes(charset));
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам за решение. Как я понял она очень стабильна,т.е. может менять не нужные значения. когда вносить его в цикл

Comment: @Альберт кто "она"? и вносить в цикл вы собрались решение, как я понял. Да, в цикле в принципе можно пробегать по какому-то массиву "ненужных слов" и заменять их на абрикосы в Вашем тексте,  но я бы тогда создал переменную с текстом файла, чтоб каждый раз не вызывать readAllBytes и write у Files, а подставил бы во write сформированную в цикле строку. .

Comment: Konstantin_SH    ,под "она"(опечатка) я имел ввиду способ, который Вы посоветовали. Если не тяжело, можете взглянуть на новую тему, где я описал эту проблему подробнее в новой теме, по ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215834/При-попытке-заменить-одну-строку-файла-он-захватывает-и-в-случайные-слова-из-др